# Receiving NSInvalidArgumentException when calling class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I'm just learning Objective-c and I am trying to create a class the generates the current date in a MySQL Timestamp format. The code compiles fine but I am getting the following error.

```
012-09-07 08:21:00.368 jsonclient[6831:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[getcurrenttime toString]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x36a9c'
```

I'm sure this is a simple answer but I have been unable to find it myself. Here's my call to the class followed by the header and .m file.

```
NSString* CurrentDate = [getcurrenttime toString];



#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface getcurrenttime : NSObject {
    NSString *toString;
}

+(NSString*) toString;

@end




#import "getcurrenttime.h"

@implementation getcurrenttime

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSString*) toString {


    NSDate *now =[NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    toString = [formatter stringFromDate:now];

    return toString;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first initialize the object.

```
getcurrenttime *objGetTime = [[getcurrenttime alloc] init];
```

And then call its method...

```
NSString* CurrentDate = [objGetTime toString];
```

You have done in case, you want a global method to call...

```
NSString* CurrentDate = [getcurrenttime toString];
```

But put "-" instead of "+" in getcurrenttime.m file.

```
+ (NSString*) toString 
{
    NSDate *now =[NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *toString = [formatter stringFromDate:now];
    return toString;
}
```

Comment: That just got me a compiler error. Now it's saying 
No visible @interface for 'getcurrenttime' declares the selector 'toString'

Comment: The second answer address that. I switched the - to + after reading another question but never switched it back when it didn't work.

Comment: I had - in the .m file. It was the header I had +. I put the + in the .m file and got a syntax error.

Comment: @Codeguy007 The only thing you have to modify is, if you are using class method (that you have defined on .h file "+(NSString*) toString", you have to declare "NSString *toString" inside the method itself.

Answer (score 2):

There is a mismatch between the interface and implementation of your class. The simplest solution is to change the follwing line:

```
+ (NSString*) toString
```

Notice the `+` instead of `-`, which indicates a class method.

Comment: the answer is correct. in your @interface section you declare `toString` as class method, and in @implementation as instance method.

Comment: In the implementation part, not the header. You've got a `+` in the header and a `-` in the implementation.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I think I misunderstood you. You wanted me to switch the + to - not the other way around. THanks